# Removing a view causing app to crash in titanium

Tags: android, view, titanium

Im working on a screen in Titanium which has a couple of input text fields and labels and a continue button. On the continue button click I am removing my variable 'container' and adding a different container with different text fields etc. It is all very basic but on my continue button click event, I am getting random crashes, maybe 60-70% of the time it crashes. The error it reports is just that message, 'unfortunately <> has closed'. Any ideas what it could potentially be? Continue button event listener below and I am getting as far as the crash 3 when I run in debug mode. The log seems to indicate I have a permission denial, but literally all I am doing is replacing a view with a different view. I'm stumped:

```
var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        title:title,
        backgroundColor:'#33336F'
    });
var Container=Ti.UI.createView({
        top:'40dp',
        width:'100%' 
    });

    var Container2=Ti.UI.createView({
        top:'40dp',
        width:'100%' 
    });

Continue_btn.addEventListener('click', function (e){

    console.log('--------------------- '+ self);
    console.log('--------------------- Title_textfield val is '+Title_textField.value);
    console.log('--------------------- Trade_picker val is '+Trade_picker.getSelectedRow(0).title);
    console.log('--------------------- Urgent_image val is '+Urgent_image.image);

    Post_array.push({
        Title:Title_textField.value,
        Trade:Trade_picker.getSelectedRow(0).title,
        Urgency:(Urgent_image.image == "urgentChecked1.png")?"0":"1",
        ClientID:8
    });

    console.log("--------------- Post_array is " + Post_array[0].Title+' - '+ Post_array[0].Trade + ' - ' + Post_array[0].Urgent);
    console.log('-------- crash 1');
    Continue_btn.setBackgroundImage('/images/continue2.png');
    console.log('-------- crash 2');
    console.log("Is self val undefined ------ "+ self.value + " or is Container val undefined ----- "+ Container.value + " or is container 2 val unndefined ------ "+ Container2.value);
    console.log("Is self typeof undefined ------ "+ typeof self + " or is Container typeof undefined ----- "+ typeof Container + " or is container 2 typeof unndefined ------ "+ typeof Container2);
    self.remove(Container);
    console.log('-------- crash 3');
    self.add(Container2);
    console.log('-------- crash 4');
    Navbar.add(BackArrow_btn);
    console.log('-------- crash 5');

});
```

The log

```
[INFO][TiAPI   (30736)]  -------- crash 1
[INFO][TiAPI   (30736)]  -------- crash 2
[INFO][TiAPI   (30736)]  Is self val undefined ------ undefined or is Container val undefined ----- undefined or is container 2 val unndefined ------ undefined
[INFO][TiAPI   (30736)]  Is self undefined ------ object or is Container undefined ----- object or is container 2 unndefined ------ object
[DEBUG][SensorManager(30736)] unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)-.d--(
[DEBUG][Sensors (30736)] Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
[INFO][Sensors (30736)] sendDelay --- 200000000
[INFO][SensorService( 2030)] info.selectDelay() ns=20000000  
[DEBUG][SensorService( 2030)] SensorDevice::setDelay, Return(true 1, false 0) =  1
[DEBUG][SensorManager(30736)] JNI - sendDelay
[INFO][SensorManager(30736)] Set normal delay = true
[DEBUG][SensorService( 2030)] SensorDevice::activating sensor handle=0 ns=20000000 
[INFO][TiAPI   (30736)]  -------- crash 3
F/libc    (30736): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1), thread 30755 (KrollRuntimeThr)
[WARN][IInputConnectionWrapper(30736)] getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
[WARN][IInputConnectionWrapper(30736)] setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
[WARN][IInputConnectionWrapper(30736)] getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

**EDIT** Updated the event listener and log info. There isn't much else code for me to include, just the declaration of labels, text fields and pickers being added to the container view and the container2 view

Answer (score 0):

did you check value of "self" ? did you tried to remove and add containers to your main view by variable name not self ?

```
//in Alloy
$.viewMain.remove( ... );
$.viewMain.add( ... );
//or JS
var viewMain = Ti.UI.createView(...);
viewMain.remove( ... );
```

Comment: self is the name of my window which is exported, I have my windows structured as modules.

Comment: I printed out self.value and it said undefined. Should my window variable have a 'value'?

Comment: yes , check if it allocate correct and filled ;) you can put that part of your code here to better understanding of issue

Comment: thanks for the reply! I have updated the question as requested. As you will see from reading the log I have updated when printing out typeof self and typeof container 1 and 2 , I am receiving 'object' so the variable itself is NOT undefined, but the actual VALUE property of the object is undefined. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: when i said value , i didn't mean value property , so you check the type of and it has value , did you tried changing the self to something else , because self is reserved name in JS

Comment: I thought so, but I was just verifying with you that we were on the same page :) I have tried that, no difference. The actual word self does not have a color change in the editor either so it's OK for now. What I did, was instead of removing and adding the contaners, I am showing and hiding them. The crashes have stopped not but its not very efficient :/